# DbSet Include Generates Incorrect SQL (Devart DotConnect Oracle)

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, devart, dotconnect

I am using Devart DotConnect For Oracle with EF Core 2.0.1. When I execute code below Entity Framework generates wrong SQL. I am considering this as a bug, however I am not sure whether I am the one who is making mistake or not. And also, I need a workaround to be able to solve this issue.

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(object[] keyValues,
    List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includes,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    Task<TEntity> model = null;

    foreach (var include in includes)
    {
            await DbSet.Include(include).LoadAsync(cancellationToken);
            model = DbSet.FindAsync(keyValues, cancellationToken);
    }

    if (model == null)
        model = DbSet.FindAsync(keyValues, cancellationToken);

    return await model;
}
```

Following code generates The SQL below

```
SELECT
"product.MhpProducts".mp_mhp_id,
"product.MhpProducts".mp_product_id,
"product.MhpProducts".mp_g_order,
"product.MhpProducts".g_end_date,
"product.MhpProducts".g_insert_by,
"product.MhpProducts".g_insert_date,
"product.MhpProducts".g_is_deleted,
"product.MhpProducts".g_start_date,
"product.MhpProducts"."mp_west_core._domain._entities._west_life._mhp_product"
FROM   mhp_product "product.MhpProducts"
       inner join (SELECT "product0".tp_id
                   FROM   tree_product "product0") "t"
               ON "product.MhpProducts".mp_product_id = "t".tp_id
ORDER  BY "t".tp_id
```

Comment: What does it mean, "it generates wrong SQL"? What's wrong with it? (Apart from the fact that enclosing oracle names into double quotes generally **is** a bad idea.)

Comment: `"product.MhpProducts"."MP_WEST_CORE._DOMAIN._ENTITIES._WEST_LIFE._MHP_PRODUCT"` is totally wrong.

Comment: Aha. Yes, it really looks wrong. "product.MhpProducts" seems to be OK, but the rest is garbage. I don't use software you do so excuse my ignorance, but - do you have any influence to code that produces that SELECT statement? I mean, can you debug it?

Comment: I now suspect that my custom naming conventions may cause this issue (it converts table and column names to higher case), altough I am not sure. I will check it out tomorrow morning.

Comment: Good luck, by all means!

Comment: Please send us a test project for reproducing via https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html.

Comment: I solved the problem. the problem was actually caused by .HasForeignKey(typeof(ExampleEntity), @"Id"). I changed this line as .HasForeignKey("Id") and it worked. I dont know why that line blowed up query generation. @Devart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. the problem was actually caused by .HasForeignKey(typeof(ExampleEntity), @"Id"). I changed this line as .HasForeignKey("Id") and it worked. I dont know why that line blowed up query generation